# Why does __init__ not get called if __new__ called with no args

Tags: python

I am trying to create (not exactly restore) an object which has its attributes saved in a database. Therefore, I do not want to call `__init__`. This desire appears to be inline with [Guido's intended use for `__new__`](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/inside-story-on-new-style-classes.html). I do not understand why `__init__` is not getting called.

Take the following snippet for example, it returns an instance of class User without calling `__init__`.

```
class User(object):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        raise Exception

user = User.__new__(User)

print user
<project.models.User object at 0x9e2dfac>
```

This is the exact behavior I want. However, my question is that I do not understand why?

According to the [python docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__) `__init__` is supposed to be called when `__new__` "returns an instance of cls."

So why is `__init__` not being even called, even though `__new__` returns a class instance?

Comment: Please post code that actually runs. Did you mean `def __init__`?

Comment: I came across this same thing and get that python doesn't do this. However the docs clearly say "If __new__() returns an instance of cls, then the new instance’s __init__() method will be invoked like __init__(self[, ...])".  Is that a doc bug or am I misinterpreting it?

Comment: @UsAaR33 You're misinterpreting it. Calling `SomeClass(args)` will (normally) do `instance = SomeClass.__new__(SomeClass, args)`, and then invoke `instance.__init__(args)` if `instance` was an instance of `SomeClass`. The docs are talking about `__new__` in the context of that sequence, not any time it's invoked, since calling `__new__` directly is even rarer than needing to define it in the first place.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The **constructor** (`User()`) is responsible for calling the **allocator** (`User.__new__()`) and the **initializer** (`User.__init__()`) in turn. Since the constructor is never invoked, the initializer is never called.

Answer (score 10):

Because you're bypassing the usual construction mechanism, by calling `__new__` directly. The `__init__`-after-`__new__` logic is in `type.__call__` (in CPython see `typeobject.c`, `type_call` function), so it happens only when you'd do `User(...)`.